# ImportError: No module named 'threading' in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, module, importerror, python-import

I have Linux Mint 17 and Python 3.4.0. I had downloaded python3.4 package for utopic so I can get Python 3.4.2. I downloaded its dependencies as well as IDLE and python3-tk for 3.4.2. After install, I did not find anything of my liking. So, with the help of Synaptic, I downgraded the packages back to the original 3.4.0 packages. I experienced no problem until I had a problem in a program I was making for time-pass. I tried to debug my app in PyCharm could no longer debug my apps in PyCharm. In the Console section, this error came up:-

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /opt/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 37770 --file "/home/ibrahim/Documents/Python/Team Rocket.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django_debug import DjangoLineBreakpoint
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pydev/django_debug.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django_frame import DjangoTemplateFrame, get_template_file_name, get_template_line
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pydev/django_frame.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydevd_file_utils import GetFileNameAndBaseFromFile
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_file_utils.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pydevd_constants import * #@UnusedWildImport
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd_constants.py", line 80, in <module>
    import threading
  ImportError: No module named 'threading'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Then I opened IDLE to debug my program to get at least some information from its underpowered debugger and neither did it work! So I started it directly by `python3 -m idlelib.idle` and it gave me the same error (but different references). Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/idlelib/idle.py", line 10, in <module>
    import idlelib.PyShell
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 10, in <module>
    import threading
ImportError: No module named 'threading'
```

I think including the program code is trivial but if you want it then I can give it to you. I have just confirmed I have downgraded all packages.

Version numbers for Python:-

```
python3.4 = 3.4.0-2ubuntu1
python3.4-minimal = 3.4.0-2ubuntu1
python3-tk = 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
idle-python3.4 = 3.4.0-2ubuntu1
PyCharm Community Edition = 3.4.1; Build = 135.1057; Running on Oracle Java 1.8.0 aka Java 8 for amd64 systems. Not running on OpenJDK.
```

Comment: Maybe your python installation is corrupted, can you try reinstalling?

Comment: @parchment it is still not working. I cannot use pip too.

Comment: More info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1503382

Comment: @Virako I have reinstalled... Thanks for your help.